# NavLink activecLassname home remain unchanged if routes changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, nav

`NavLink` `"/"` route component `activeclassname` remains unchanged even the route changes on `"react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"`. I try `exact` path for `"/"` routing and also ternary `className` but no effects.

So my UI seems two active classes when routing.

Here is my code

```
<nav className='side-nav'>
  <NavLink to='/' className='side-nav-links' activeclassname='active'>
    <p>Home</p>
  </NavLink>
  <div className='side-nav-div'>
    <div><p>PUBLIC</p></div>
    <NavLink to='/Questions' className='side-nav-links' activeclassname='active'>
      <img src={Globe} alt="Globe" />
      <p style={{paddingLeft: "10px"}}> Questions </p>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/Tags' className='side-nav-links' activeclassname='active' style={{paddingLeft: "40px"}}>
      <p>Tags</p>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/Users' className='side-nav-links' activeclassname='active' style={{paddingLeft: "40px"}}>
      <p>Users</p>
    </NavLink>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

It appears you are referencing the RRDv5 `NavLink` component props.

- The RRDv6 `NavLink` components removed the `activeClassName` prop. It was replaced by a `className` callback function taking an `isActive` prop.
- There is also no `exact` prop, which was ***also*** removed.

The first discrepancy is masked by the fact that the `NavLink` component uses an `"active"` class by default when a link matches the current URL path. The other issue is that the link will match when any of the target path's sub-routes are active.

## Solution

Use the `end` prop to keep from also matching sub-routes.

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to
> render a link that is only active at the website root and not any
> other URLs, you can use:
>
> ```
> <NavLink to="/" end>
>   Home
> </NavLink>
> ```

Your code:

```
<nav className='side-nav'>
  <NavLink
    to='/'
    className='side-nav-links'
    end // <-- pass end prop to match only "/", not any sub-routes
  >
    <p>Home</p>
  </NavLink>
  <div className='side-nav-div'>
    <div><p>PUBLIC</p></div>
    <NavLink to='/Questions' className='side-nav-links'>
      <img src={Globe} alt="Globe" />
      <p style={{ paddingLeft: "10px" }}>Questions</p>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink
      to='/Tags'
      className='side-nav-links'
      style={{ paddingLeft: "40px" }}
    >
      <p>Tags</p>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink
      to='/Users'
      className='side-nav-links'
      style={{ paddingLeft: "40px" }}
    >
      <p>Users</p>
    </NavLink>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If you needed to conditionally apply an alternative className when active then use a callback function.

Example:

```
<NavLink
  to="...."
  className={({ isActive }) => 
    ['side-nav-links', isActive ? "myActiveClass" : null]
      .filter(Boolean)
      .join(" ")
  }
>
  ....
</NavLink>
```

See the [NavLink docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) for more details.